# How do I return a boolean field value based on if there's a reference in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
let getLinkTopicsSql = "SELECT     Topic.Id, Topic.Name
                        FROM       Topic
                        INNER JOIN LinkTopic
                              ON   LinkTopic.TopicId = Topic.Id
                        INNER JOIN Link
                              ON   LinkTopic.LinkId = Link.Id
                        WHERE  Link.Id = @LinkId"
```

I need to update the fields returned from:

```
SELECT     Topic.Id, Topic.Name
```

to

```
SELECT     Topic.Id, Topic.Name, IsFeatured
```

However the *IsFeatured* custom field that I want to return is determined to be true only if the record exists in the *FeaturedTopic* table.

The FeaturedTopic table has a column called *TopicId*.

As a result, I want to add another *INNER JOIN* to the query. However, I know that that will ignore the links that are not featured that still need to be returned.

**Question:**

How do I return a boolean field value based on if there's a reference in another table?

Comment: Help us help you - please share your tables' strcutures

Comment: Try using a left join instead of an inner join. Then you can use a case expression to check the existence in the other table. But there is no such thing as a boolean in sql server.

Comment: Use `left join` and use a calculated column that compares to `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on `outer joins` ([link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx)), esp. left outer joins. That will enable you to keep the left parts of the query so far and join either the values in IsFeatured or get null values for them.

**LEFT OUTER JOIN**

```
SELECT     Topic.Id, Topic.Name, 
    case when FeaturedTopic.TopicId is null then 0 else 1 end as IsFeatured
FROM       Topic
INNER JOIN LinkTopic
              ON   LinkTopic.TopicId = Topic.Id
INNER JOIN Link
              ON   LinkTopic.LinkId = Link.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN FeaturedTopic 
              ON   Topic.Id = TopicId
WHERE  Link.Id = @LinkId"
```

**SUBQUERY**

Another way is a subquery (shaky on syntax) which might be slower on huge sets then the left outer join solution:

```
SELECT     Topic.Id, 
           Topic.Name, 
           isnull( (select 1 from FeaturedTopic where TopicId = Topic.Id),0) as IsFeatured 
FROM       Topic
INNER JOIN LinkTopic
              ON   LinkTopic.TopicId = Topic.Id
INNER JOIN Link
              ON   LinkTopic.LinkId = Link.Id
WHERE  Link.Id = @LinkId"
```

Or something along the lines of

```
case when exists (select 1 from FeaturedTopic where FeaturedTopic.TopicId = Topic.Id) then 1 else 0 end as IsFeatured
```

The exact syntax depends on the flavour of DB you use (Oracle, TSql, MYSql, ...)